# No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler' has been registred .net 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mediatr

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Im using asp.net core .net 6 and  MediatR 12.0.1 and i'm not using on purpose MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection which is deprecated.
In my Program.cs file i have:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

And when im trying to ese MediatR i have error

```
No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler' has been registred
```

hire in order controller i have this error:

```
    // GET: api/Orders
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderDto>>> GetOrders()
        {
            return await Mediator.Send(new GetOrderListQuery()); //error hire
       
        }
```

MediatR is used in controller like that:

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ISender _mediator = null!;

        protected ISender Mediator => _mediator ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISender>();
    }
}
```

and my Ordercontroller inherits BaseApiController

What im doing wrong?

[EDIT 1]:
One important thing is that my Queries Commands and Handlers exists in second project called Application.
It is working when I used this registration:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(
    typeof(GetOrderListHandler).Assembly,
    typeof(GetOrderListQuery).Assembly
    ));
```

How can I do it automaticly?
Project structure:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbA7.png

[EDIT 2]:
I found quite good solution after many tests, you have to point one Class from assembly and MedaitR will register all:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<GetOrderListHandler>(
));
```

Answer (score 5):

The next approach is better, because this can help you with performance at the begining and readability:

**First step:** Into project application where you have the controllers, you should create a class for dependency injection, e,g.,

[image]

Here you can add all your dependencies relate the current project

```
public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
             services.AddMediatR(cf => cf.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly));

            return services;

        }
    }
```

**Second step:** Add as reference into the main project

[image]

**Third step:** Add the extension into `Program.cs` or `Startup.cs`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when Mediatr is not registered in the project that has the Commands and Query. If you have different projects make sure mediatr is registered inside the executing project not in the referenced project.

NB: Mediatr should not be registered in the referenced project.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
Cfg => Cfg.registerservicesfromassemblies(appdomain.currentdomain.getassemblies())
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, i tried and the result is like this:


 Message=No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Catalog.Orders.GetOrderListQuery,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Application.Catalog.Orders.OrderDto]]' has been registered.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can try : foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(assembly));
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your Program.cs:

```
foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(assembly));
}
```

This approach registers all your assemblies. This works for me